# how to build hair like this?

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, hair

it looks like one mesh, and no using the particle to make it.  how can I make the hair like this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe a texture?

Comment: hello please share the hair object: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Looks like so-called hair cards which are just joined to one object. Hard cards are textured planes. You can create them with help of hair particles.